# CardView Shadow like this?

Tags: android, android-cardview

I want to make like this. How to get exactly like this (see image below)? I tried `layer-list` but not able to get this view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#afbdc3" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="5px">
        <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#91a5af" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="10px">
        <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#79919d" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And so on

[image]

[LIKE THIS LAYER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4bAh.png)

Comment: sorry @Rishabh new in stackoverflow , i will remember next time

Comment: do you have answer ?

Comment: Which shadow do you want exactly?

Comment: cardview shadow

Comment: create a png file and set as background.

Comment: i know , but i want image/background color in shadow layer that's by i post it here